# Member online counter

Tags: javascript, discord.js

My member counter didn't work
Why always my channel have name "online 0" 0 errors, console log working I don't know why
This is my code

````
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('693805106906398722');
    setInterval(() =>{
        const memberCount = guild.memberCount;
        const channel = guild.channels.cache.get('824050164376666182');
        channel.setName(`Użytkownicy ${memberCount.toLocaleString()}`);
        console.log('Member Status: Updating...');
    }, 1200000);
   setInterval(() =>{
        
            const memberCollection = guild.members.cache;
            const online = memberCollection.filter(member => {
            member.presence.status === 'online'
        }).size;

        const channel1 = guild.channels.cache.get('824050194177720391');
        channel1.setName(`Online ${online}`);
        console.log('Member online Status: Updating...');
        
    }, 1200); 

} ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do you have Intents Enabled in your bot? If you do not: Then please do it in the Discord Developers Portal for your Application. You need to enable `Guild Members` intent. Also please do not forget to update your stuff in the Client Constructor (aka `const client = new Discord.Client()`) so that you can access the guild Member information!
2. There's a mistake in the code

```js
const online = memberCollection.filter(member => {
    member.presence.status === 'online'
}).size;
```

Please make it

```js
const online = memberCollection.filter(member => {
    return member.presence.status === 'online'
}).size;
```

Since for the filter to work, you need to have a function which returns a boolean and you're not returning anything from your filter function, it is getting a bit messed up.